# How to use eth1 as failsafe system for eth0?

Tags: networking, network-bonding

How to configure eth1 to be a failsafe system for eth0.

When **eth0** is down **eth1** goes up, and when **eth0** is up **eth1** goes down

Comment: @Alex Please don't post the same question twice; instead, you can add more information to any of your posts by editing.

Answer (score 8):

What you are looking to set up is called [Network Bonding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding).

This is also called "**port trunking** or **link aggregation** (which) means combining several network interfaces (NICs) to a single link, providing either high-availability, load-balancing, maximum throughput, or a combination of these."

In this case, you will want to set up a [**Mode 1 active-backup bonding**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding#Descriptions_of_bonding_modes) configuration.

1. Install package to allowing interface bonding**

   - First, you will need to install the *ifenslave* package which allows interfaces to be added and removed from a bonding group.
   - Install the ***ifenslave*** package from the Ubuntu Software Center:

   [image: Install via the software center]

   - or, you can install the package from the command line:

     `sudo apt-get install ifenslave-2.6`
2. Modify config to load bonding module

   Next, you will modify your `/etc/modules` file to ensure that the
   bonding module is loaded.

   `sudo gedit /etc/modules` and add the following line to the bottom of the file:

   ```
   bonding mode=active-backup miimon=100 max_bonds=2 primary=eth0
   ```

   The **miimon** option tells how often to monitor(in milliseconds) the interface for failure and can be adjusted as needed.
3. load the bonding kernel module:

   ```
   sudo modprobe bonding
   ```
4. Define the bond group

   Finally, you will define the bond group in the file `/etc/network/interfaces` and restart the networking service.

   `sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces/`

   ```
   auto bond0
     iface bond0 inet static
       address 192.168.1.10
       gateway 192.168.1.1
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       network 192.168.1.0
       broadcast 192.168.1.255
       bond-slaves none
       bond-mode 1
       bond-miimon 100
       post-up ifenslave bond0 eth0 eth1
       pre-down ifenslave -d bond0 eth0 eth1

   auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet manual
     bond-master bond0
     bond-primary eth0 eth1

   auto eth1
    iface eth1 inet manual
     bond-master bond0
     bond-primary eth0 eth1
   ```
5. Restart the networking service

   `sudo service networking restart`

**Note: This does not allow for bonding between two different network types (i.e. You cannot bond between an ethernet card and a wireless connection.)**

**Also, this has nothing to do with multi-homing between two ISPs and is beyond the scope of this question.**

References:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding#Ethernet_Bonding_modes

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1888967

http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-modules-ethernet.html#s3-modules-bonding-directives

Answer (score 2):

You need network [bonding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding).

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding:

> Bonding, also called port trunking or link aggregation means combining
>   several network interfaces (NICs) to a single link, providing either
>   high-availability, load-balancing, maximum throughput, or a
>   combination of these.

Install ifenslave (`sudo apt-get install ifenslave-2.6`), and configure `/etc/network/interfaces` like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
       address 192.168.0.1
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       gateway 192.168.0.254
       slaves eth0 eth1
       bond-mode active-backup
```